# CREATE_FAILED Bucketpolicy - Unknown field Fn::Join

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

My Cloudformation stack fails and keeps getting rolled back because of the following S3 bucket policy. The referenced S3 bucket is a separate bucket meant for CloudTrail logs (as I read that such a thing is best practice when using CloudTrail). The bucket gets created along with the rest of the stack during the cloudFormation process: [stackname]-cloudtraillogs-[randomstring]

I tried not using any functions to specify the bucket, but that doesn't seem to work. My guess is because it then goes looking for a bucket 'cloudtraillogs' and can't find any bucket with that name. Using a Fn::Join with a reference might solve that(?), but then CloudFormation gives 'Unknown field Fn::Join' when evaluating bucket policy.

Anyone who can spot what I might be doing wrong here?

**Bucketpolicy**

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "policycloudtraillogs": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Bucket": {
          "Ref": "cloudtraillogs"
        },
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20160224",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                    {
                      "Ref": "cloudtraillogs"
                    },
                    "/*"
                  ]
                ]
            },
            {
              "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20160224",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "s3:PutObject",
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                    {
                      "Ref": "cloudtraillogs"
                    },
                    "/AWSLogs/myAccountID/*"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                  "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template does not appear to be valid JSON. Your first policy statement (`AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20160224`) is missing a closing bracket `}` for its `Resource` object.